# Jenkins: how to find out newly created projects?

Tags: jenkins

My manager wants to produce a list of newly created project every week. Is there a way to achieve this?

---

Based on this:https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/disableAllJobs.groovy, and this:https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Display+list+of+projects+that+were+built+more+than+1+day+ago., I wrote the following scriptler,but it gives java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getTimestamp() on null object, after displaying the newly created project in the last 7 days. Can anyone help me to get rid of this error?

```
hour=24;
minute=60;
second=60;
oneDayInSecond=hour*minute*second;
sevenDayInSecond=hour*minute*second*7;
now=Calendar.instance;
list=[];
println("${now.time}");

checkNewProjects(Hudson.instance.items)

def checkNewProjects(items) {
  for (item in items) {    
    if (item.class.canonicalName != 'com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder') {
        build_time=item.getFirstBuild().getTimestamp();
        if (now.time.time/1000-build_time.time.time/1000<sevenDayInSecond){
            item.save()
            println(item.name)
            println("\t\tFirst build was built in less than 7 days");
            println("\t\tFirst built was at ${build_time.time}");
            list<< item;
        } 
    } else {
        checkNewProjects(((com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder) item).getItems())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you Jenkins instance has JobConfigHistory plugin already in place, then you can query that to get (JSON output) and print what you are looking for. The date of creation is pretty straight forward to get using the jobConfigHistory plugin and the /jobConfigHistory/api/json endpoint.

Choose the earliest json object (the earliest two are usually noted as "operation": "Changed" for some reason) or choose the json object that has "operation": "Created".

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28164 see for more details but so far JobConfigHistory plugin can help.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have access to your Jenkins machines and your Jenkins is deployed in Linux, you can:
`find /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ -mtime +7 -type d -maxdepth 1`

Comment: There are several problems with this approach: 1. `-mtime +7` finds files _older_ than 7 days, 2. this finds lots of files, not just a list of projects, 3. a job directory may be modified when a build occurs -- perhaps this is what the OP wanted, but the original question sounds more like "list the jobs created in the past week"

Comment: @DaveBacher 1,2 - correct, fixed, please consider re-upvote.

3 - It's open to interpretation but your perspective sound right, edited.

Comment: Thanks but we are on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the new question: `item.getFirstBuild()` is returning Null. You must have a job that has no builds. You should check whether `item.getFirstBuild()` is not Null before retrieving the build timestamp.

```
first_build = item.firstBuild // or item.getFirstBuild()
if (first_build) {
  build_time = first_build.timestamp
  ...
} else {
  println "${item.name} has no builds"
}
```

Based on your code, you've changed the requirements from "detect newly created jobs" to "find jobs with their oldest recorded build in the past week". You should be aware that if you expire old builds in your job configuration, the new code may report false positives if you have a job that is built frequently. For example, if you only keep the last 10 builds, then if those 10 builds are all performed within the last week, the code that looks at the oldest build date will report this as a new job regardless of when the job was actually created.

Comment: 1. You are right the error is due to some projects has never been run so have no build. 2. So what's the proper way to find a newly created project? Thanks!